# What is the available text space on a RaisedButton?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I'm trying to put text on it, but some trailing letters wrap when there looks to be plenty of room on the current line.

```
            child: RaisedButton(
              child: Text("Order\nTruffles"),
```

Result is left justified, but wrapping too early. Everything normal in a wider button, but it just seems to be wasting space:

`|  Order     |
|  Truffle   |
|  s         |`

Any way to get farther out to the edge? Thanks.

Comment: have you tried the `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly` ?

Comment: That's the default padding for a RaisedButton widget based on Material Design. Instead of changing the padding, you might want to create your own customize button.

Comment: @AlécioCarvalho: I don't see mainAxisAlignment as a button attribute. What did you mean for me to do?

Comment: @JeromeEscalante: Thanks. Yeah, I kinda figured that's all you get for an inbuilt button. I just dropped my font size down a little.